# For $n$ houses arranged in a circle, a man goes clockwise skipping $i$ houses every time. For what value of $n$ does he visit each house?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

**A man wants to visit every house a circular road with $n$ houses. For this he starts at a house and then moves clockwise, always skipping exactly $i$ houses before stopping at the next house. For which values of $i$ does he visit every house?** I am assuming that $i<n$

I think we need to use residual systems. But I cannot figure out how. For example, say we have $42$ houses. One residual system of $42$ is $\{1,2,3....42\}$. But this does not give use anz new information. of course, I know that $\phi(42) = 12$. But this does not help me either. Are these values actually useful? Or do I need to use another method?

**Note: I would prefer methods that do not involve brute force, or rather any kind of program based computation (But if you have a method, please share it anyways.)**

Comment: For which values of $i$ does he visit every house?  $i=1$, I guess

Comment: @LuckyChouhan No, if he he skips 1 house everytime, he will end up skipping half of the houses if $n$ is even

Comment: oh yeah! You're right.

Comment: By the dupe: $\bmod n\!:\  x\to a+(i+1)x$ is surjective (onto) iff $i+1$ is coprime to $n\ \ $

Comment: Sorry @BillDubuque, did not know about the dupe. I still do not know how I would have found that by myself, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both $i$ and $n$ have no prime factors in common, all houses will be visited.

Some explanatory examples:
If $i=6$ and $n=12$, you can easily see that only 2 houses will be visited.
If $i=8$ and $n=12$, you'll end up with 3 houses being visited.
If $i=5$ and $n=12$, you'll end up with all houses being visited.

(By the way, there is no reason for $i<n$)

Comment: So the condition is that they must be co-prime? Can you prove it too?

Comment: @NaitikMundra: yes, indeed.

Comment: Simply said: you are looking for a value $a$, for which you can say that for all values of $x$: $(x \cdot i) \mod n \neq a$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242). It should be $i+1$ is coprime to $n$, not $i\ \ $